# blade @push scripts , jquery: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a component file:

`my-component.blade.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
......
</head>
<body>
........

  <script src="/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
  @stack('scripts')
</body>

</html>
```

`otherfile.blade.php`

```
<x-my-component>
.....

@push("scripts")
  <script defer>
    console.log($("body")); // a simple print element
  </script>
@endpush
</x-my-component>
```

`browser console`

`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function`

I have tried to use `yield` and `section` and got the same result
how can I solve this problem? (I have the jquery file on my public vendor so there's no way the problem is about jquery import path)

[image]

Comment: "so there's no way the problem is about jquery import path" — That sounds like an assumption you should test by using the Network tab in the browser's developer tools.

Comment: update the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation for the script element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script):

> Warning: [The `defer`] attribute must not be used if the src attribute is absent (i.e. for inline scripts), in this case it would have no effect.

So the script that loads jQuery is executed *after the document is parsed* and the script which tries to use it is executed *immediately* (because the `defer` attribute is ignored) which is **before** `$` is added to the scope of the page.